# Active user count

Tags: c++, lock, multiple-users

Trying to understand how a software is counting concurrent users connected.
Tried to analyze the machine on which is installed. (Registry and files modified) but nothing found. Best approach ?

Edit: As suggested wiresharks worked.

Comment: There are *numerous* ways a program can do this.  The real question is are you *supposed* to be limited to two users?  Are you trying to circumvent your license?  If not, have you contacted support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software needs to find the number of concurrent users ON THE NETWORK. Thus it won't do any local changes (files, registry) on your PC.

One possibility is that this program is using a central license server software which is running on one of the computers and manages the shared licenses. But you didn't talk about such a program on your PC.

Therefore I assume it will rather have a built-in TCP or UDP server and client connections, and it will search the network for open ports of connections of other instances of this program on other PCs. Use Sysinternals TCPView and Wireshark to detect possible network communication.

Comment: Indeed Wireshark allowed me to undersand how this is working and to resolve a bug. Thanks.